# React Native View PDF

Tags: react-native, react-native-linking

I have a react-native app which opens a PDF document using `Linking` as shown below:

```
const handlePress = () => {
    Linking.openURL(
      "https://link/to/file.pdf"
    );
};
```

The problem with the above code is that it opens the web browser and downloads the file. Isn't there any way through which I can open the file via the default PDF Viewer of the device?

Comment: You can download the file and open it with a third-party app on your phone with  RN-Fetch-blob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the PDF with [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) to your phone storage and open it with default PDF viewer like below:

```js
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'

const android = RNFetchBlob.android;

RNFetchBlob.config({
  addAndroidDownloads: {
    useDownloadManager: true,
    title: "awesome.pdf",
    description: "An awesome PDF",
    mime: "application/pdf",
    mediaScannable: true,
    notification: true,
  },
})
  .fetch("GET", `http://www.example.com/awesome.pdf`)
  .then((res) => {
    const path = res.path();
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(path);
    } else {
      android.actionViewIntent(path, "application/pdf");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I implement the same in an Expo managed project?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Expo.

Comment: Could you accept the answer? Maybe an upvote? Thanks.